Where can I find prof. Wittenberg's TU Delft aircraft propulsion notes?
In threads like this one (Why do jet engines have a maximum speed?) I stumbled upon some pics that were taken from prof. Wittenberg's lecture notes at TU Delft. I have looked everywhere on the internet but could not find them. Can someone tell me where I can get them?
Thank you very much
Federico

Have you tried your local library? They are magicians in finding literature from all kinds of places.

Um - yeah the handout in question, VTH-D 14, dates from quite a while before the start of the internet. And it is in Dutch.
I have a treasured paper copy (with an imprint of a cup of coffee), which was already over a decade old when we were lectured on it.

There is an on-line repository of TU Delft publications, entering H Wittenberg in the search area yields quite a few results.
